# I'm trying to run this code, but I get an error, TypeError: predict() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, machine-learning

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
#import dataSet and split them to dependent and independent
dataset = pd.read_csv('Position_Salaries.csv')
i= dataset.iloc[:, 1:2].values # to treat it as an array
d = dataset.iloc[:, 2].values
# Fitting Simple Linear Regression to the Training set
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(i,d)
# Fitting polynomial Regression to the dataset
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
poly=PolynomialFeatures(degree=4)
i_poly=poly.fit_transform(i)

regressor2=LinearRegression()
regressor2.fit(i_poly,d)
plt.scatter(i,d,color='red')
plt.plot(i,regressor.predict(i),color='blue')
plt.title('Truth or Bluff (linear Regression)')
plt.xlabel('Position Level')
plt.ylabel('Salary')
plt.show()
i_grid=np.arange(min(i),max(i),0.1)
i_grid=i_grid.reshape(len(i_grid),1)  #  len(i_grid) to make code dynamic 
plt.scatter(i,d,color='red')
plt.plot(i_grid,regressor2.predict(poly.fit_transform(i_grid)),color='blue')  
plt.title('Truth or Bluff (Polynomial Regression)')
plt.xlabel('Position Level')
plt.ylabel('Salary')
plt.show()
regressor.predict(0,6.5)
regressor2.predict(poly.fit_transform(6.5))
```

Comment: We don't know on which of the approximately 6 occurrences of `predict` the error is.

Comment: I'm guessing it's the second-to-last line. Use `reg.predict(0)`. You don't need to provide the y values to predict.